# Difficulty with linq and data table

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, linq, datatable

I am trying to filter records via Linq on my datatable, but somehow The result is displaying a table with no errors but a line saying "row has errors", in a column of table. My code is as following:
Any suggestions?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;


namespace linq_app
{
    public partial class admins : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcon"].ToString());

            con.Open();

            SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand();
            sqlcmd.CommandText = "select * from user_info";
            sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            sqlcmd.Connection = con;
            SqlDataReader sqlreader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("first_name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("last_name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Email_ID", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Contact", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Address", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Role", typeof(string));


            while (sqlreader.Read())
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["first_name"] = sqlreader["first_name"];
                dr["last_name"] = sqlreader["last_name"];
                dr["Email_ID"] = sqlreader["email"];
                dr["Contact"] = sqlreader["contact1"];
                dr["Address"] = sqlreader["address"];
                dr["Role"] = sqlreader["role"];
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }


            var results = from myRow in dt.AsEnumerable()
                          where myRow.Field<string>("Role").ToString() == "admin".ToString()
                          select myRow;

            //dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;


            //DataClasses1DataContext dc = new DataClasses1DataContext();
            //var admin = from records in dc.GetTable<user_info>() 
            //              where records.role =="admin"
            //              select records;
            GridView1.DataSource = results;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you do sqlreader["column name"] it returns an object. Perhaps test if it is null, or some other type beside String?

Comment: Yo could try removing the Where on your linq initially, and see how that works. If that is returning the same "row has error" message it will be because there's a problem with the way you are pulling the data or building your DataTable. Debug that and make sure you have the data you want form the DB. But as lazyberezovsky has pointed out, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code.

Comment: I've tried that too.. its displaying the same line but this time it has a table with five rows.. and previously it had two lines since there are total five users, two of whom are admins.

Comment: I am really stuck now! Cant find any solution to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to remove `ToString` call. It will throw exception if there is `null` in roles column. And create new datatable from filtered rows:

```
var results = from myRow in dt.AsEnumerable()
              where myRow.Field<string>("Role") == "admin"
              select myRow;

GridView1.DataSource = results.CopyToDataTable(); // create datatable
GridView1.DataBind();
```

BTW why not to use Linq to Entities instead? You will be able to do filtering on database side.

Comment: No, cant do it using linq to entities since I have to do it like this only, part of an assignment.

Comment: @ankitaalung if datatable contains data, then there is nothing wrong with your code

Comment: @ankitaalung see update. I verified it all works fine. Also when retrieving connection string use `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcon"].ConnectionString`